# Using sezpoz for a mixed java scala project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, annotations

I am using sezpoz in a mixed java/scala project compiled in Eclipse. It works perfectly fine (after a few modifications mentioned here: http://imagej.net/pipermail/imagej-devel/2011-January/000305.html) at locating the java annotations

```
    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Indexable(type = TIPLPluginFactory.class)
public static @interface PluginInfo {
    /**
     * The name of the plugin (VfilterScale is Filter so is FilterScale)
     * @return
     */
    String pluginType();
...
}
```

Is used as the annotation for labeling the plugins and they are read with the following function.

```
public static List<PluginInfo> getAllPlugins() {
    for (final IndexItem<PluginInfo, TIPLPluginFactory> item : Index.load(
            PluginInfo.class, TIPLPluginFactory.class)) {
        final PluginInfo bName = item.annotation();
...
```

The java plugins have this in the class

```
@TIPLPluginManager.PluginInfo(pluginType = "DistGrow",
        desc="Full memory distance growing",
        sliceBased=false)
final public static TIPLPluginManager.TIPLPluginFactory myFactory = new TIPLPluginManager.TIPLPluginFactory() {
    @Override
    public ITIPLPlugin get() {
        return new DistGrow();
    }
};
```

The scala plugins have the nearly identical code

```
@TIPLPluginManager.PluginInfo(pluginType = "GrayAnalysis",
        desc="Spark-based gray value analysis",
        sliceBased=false,sparkBased=true)
val myFactory: TIPLPluginManager.TIPLPluginFactory = new TIPLPluginManager.TIPLPluginFactory() {
    override def get():ITIPLPlugin = {
        return new ShapeAnalysis;
    }
};
```

Any idea why this doesn't work or how it might need to be modified to make it work correctly? An easy hack would be to make a new java class to have all these annotations for making the scala ones but that does not seem very elegant

Comment: When you say this "doesn't work", what do you mean? Compilation error? Any warnings? Runtime exception?

Comment: The code compiles perfectly fine, it just doesn't get found when getAllPlugins is run (nor do the Annotation files get generated in the build folder). If I extract the factory and rewrite it as java code it works fine but that requires a seperate entry for each class defeating some of the purpose of using sezpoz/di

Comment: If you need a static field in Scala, you might be out of luck.